# How do I add a exception to the document for a menu system, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I add exceptions to the document? 
For example within DIV(.rtmenu) I want to exclude links with the class (a.menu-arrow). So if I click/mousedown on (a.menu-arrow)...the DIV(.rtmenu) doesn't fadeOut?

```
$('.rtmenu').live('click', function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
$(document).mousedown(function() { $('.rtmenu').fadeOut(200); });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a stop propgation to the menu links as well, like this:

```
$('.rtmenu').live('click', function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
$('.a-menu-arrow').live('mousedown', function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
$(document).mousedown(function() { $('.rtmenu').fadeOut(200); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function:

```
$('.rtmenu').not('a.menu-arrow').live(...
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ You'll need to use :not